# Testcafe execution is not happening, but displaying tests as passed

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, ui-automation, testcafe, ui-testing

I am new to **testcafe** and i am trying to work on a framework

**Issue**
The issue i am facing is, the test execution is opening the chrome browser and immediately results with one passed test without any execution happening on browser

Can someone help me to fix this?

My code looks like below

**Page Object File**

```
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe';
import CommonFunctions from '../commons/common-fns'

export default class LoginPage extends CommonFunctions {    
    constructor () {
        super();
    }

     login() {
         this.typeText(this.emailTxtBox, '');
         this.click(this.nextBttn);
         this.typeText(this.emailTxtBox, '');
         this.click(this.microsoftNextBttn);
         this.typeText(this.passwordTxtBox, '');
    }
}
```

Comment: Try debugging and find which step exactly fails.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `await` operator before your async functions as follows:

```js
test("My First Test", async () => {
    await loginPage.login();
});

async login() {
     await this.typeText(this.emailTxtBox, 'email@gmail.com');
     await this.click(this.nextBttn);
     await this.typeText(this.emailTxtBox, 'email@gmail.com');
     await this.click(this.microsoftNextBttn);
     await this.typeText(this.passwordTxtBox, 'pet@#$343242^&*');
     await this.click(this.signinBttn);
     await this.click(this.noBttn);
}
```